# Erro ao adicionar Stored Procedure no mapa em Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Ao adicionar uma SP com parâmetros de com tipo de dados data, ao adicionar a seguinte informação de erro é visualizada.

Variáveis na SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spExtractoTSL]
    ,@DataInicial DATETIME = 0
    ,@DataFinal DATETIME = 0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Penso que as variáveis do tipo `DateTime` não podem ter valores inteiros. Experimente dar uma data mínima, por exemplo '1900-01-01'.

Comment: Bom dia amigo,
Da uma olhada se isso te atende?
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425870/using-datetime-in-a-sqlparameter-for-stored-procedure-format-error)

Comment: @acamiloMoz, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Ainda não consegui!